# How can I connect my sidebar to my footer?

Tags: html, css

I want to connect a sidebar to footer. I used `html,body {position:relative; height:100%;}` but it does not work in my code. What's my mistake? `height: 100vh` looks strange. How else can I do?

I want this:

[image: What I want]

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
      background: #e1dfb9; 
    }

    ul, li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .col-sm-3, .col-sm-9 {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }

    .col-sm-3  { width: 26%; }
    .col-sm-9  { width: 74%; }

    .col-pad { padding-right: 10px; }


    .container {
      min-width: 960px; 
      max-width: 1920px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #f0f0f0; 
    }

    .sidebar_wrap {
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 34px 16px;
      height: 100%;
    }

    html,body {
      height: 100%; 
      position: relative;
    }
    .main { 
      min-height: 100%; 
      height: 100%;
    }
    .hFooter { 
      height: 114px; 
    }
    .footer { 
      background: gray; 
      color: #fff;
      height: 114px; 
      margin-top: -114px; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-pad">
        <div class="sidebar_wrap">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint commodi, inventore, quisquam, laboriosam veniam recusandae repellat quo animi fugiat nulla debitis. Eos magni, excepturi eveniet! Molestias quasi consequatur quo tenetur sequi, a quia! Iusto autem accusamus quo officia explicabo eaque doloremque nesciunt! Facilis repellendus culpa, eum reiciendis nesciunt quisquam facere iusto, ipsa harum ab deleniti officia libero totam reprehenderit illo expedita voluptatum consequuntur repudiandae recusandae dolor commodi quas. Omnis voluptas, iusto ipsum, quo eaque dignissimos sunt assumenda! Sequi labore libero expedita asperiores iusto consequuntur repellendus facilis ratione, possimus, in, a aliquid. Doloribus error animi excepturi dolorum, dolorem odit velit voluptatibus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="ext">
          <div id="int"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hFooter"></div>
  </div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify *"connect sidebar to footer"*. What should the layout look like? Perhaps make a simple image and add it to your question.

Comment: did you try removing margin-top: -114px for your code?

Comment: Fred Gandt, apdated

Comment: vikrantnegi007, removing, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

You should consider removing browser-added margins and padding from either all elements using the asterisk [(*) "select all" selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp) in your css, or just  remove margins and padding from your html and body at the top of your css.

You will more likely get the expected result then

```
  html, body{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
   }
/*removes margin/padding from html and body at top of css
   then continue with other css*/
```

or

```
* { 
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}

/*if you use this option [put at top of css], any margins/padding will be 
 removed from all elements, but any following css that adds margin/padding 
 will be accounted for (so you can stll have margins etc.. it's not 
 completely "wipe-all")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Edit, but nothing has changed(

Comment: @z_u_l first, there's 2 colons in ::before and ::after if you're going to do it that way, also box sizing alters the height/width: see http://callmenick.com/post/box-sizing-reset-border-box. In addition, you haven't stripped the default browser-added margin and padding in the html and body (which was  recommended, and would have been removed using either option in my answer)